# Showing test coverage of simpletests

Tags: 6, testing

I'm looking to start using simpletest (or possibly go to pressflow) to test some Drupal modules I am working on.

I would like to get some information about the code that is covered by these tests. I have seen that it is possible to get this information from xdebug.

I have also seen these [code coverage reports](http://cwgordon.com/coverage/coverage/html/1), but have no idea how they were generated.

Are there instructions on how to set this up anywhere? (Ideally for D6)

Comment: Partial answer: there's a module for [Code coverage](http://drupal.org/project/code_coverage), it's currently for Drupal 7 but there's a [Drupal 6 port](http://drupal.org/node/405934).

Comment: Thanks for that, I had seen the module but didn't see the D6 issue.